# convolving a gaussian mask on an image, without using built-in functions

Tags: c++, opencv, mask, gaussian, convolution

I want to apply canny edge detection to an image without using the cvcanny function, so a part of the required steps is to apply the gaussian mask for which i have 2 masks for x and y direction. Now the problem is that whenever i try the convolution of the mask onto my image, the execution breaks due to "access violation".
Why does this happen and how can i overcome this?

```
//DECLARATIONS..
double maskx[3][3];
double masky[3][3];
double convx[1000][1000]={0};
double convy[1000][1000]={0};
double M[1000][1000]={0};  //magnitude
double slope[1000][1000];


int gaussian_mask()
{
int MaskRadius=SIGMA*3;
double eq1;
double exp=2.71828183;

for(int p=-MaskRadius; p<=MaskRadius; p++)
{
for(int q=-MaskRadius; q<=MaskRadius; q++)
{
    eq1=-1*(p*p + q*q)/(2*SIGMA);
    maskx[p+MaskRadius][q+MaskRadius]=-1*q*(pow(exp,eq1));
    masky[p+MaskRadius][q+MaskRadius]=-1*p*(pow(exp,eq1));
}
}

return MaskRadius;
}

IplImage* convolve(IplImage *im)
{
int MaskRadius=gaussian_mask();
int row=im->width;
int col=im->height;
printf("row: %d, col= %d",row,col);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

IplImage *pix=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im), im->depth, 1);      //converting 3 channel   to 1 channel
cvSetImageCOI(im,1);
cvCopy(im,pix);
cout<<endl<<"No. of channels = "<<pix->nChannels;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

for(int i=MaskRadius; i<=row-MaskRadius; i++)             //convolving the image
{
uchar* ptr1 = (uchar*) (pix->imageData + i * pix->widthStep);
uchar* ptr0 = (uchar*) (pix->imageData + (i-1) * pix->widthStep);
uchar* ptr2 = (uchar*) (pix->imageData + (i+1) * pix->widthStep);
for(int j=MaskRadius; j<=col-MaskRadius; j++)
 {
     cout<<endl<<i<<" , "<<j;
     convx[i][j]=(double)ptr1[j-1]*maskx[1][0]+ptr1[j]*maskx[1][1]+ptr1[j+1]*maskx[1][2] + (ptr2[j-1]*maskx[0][0]+ptr2[j]*maskx[0][1]+ptr2[j+1]*maskx[0] + ptr0[j-1]*maskx[2][0]+ptr0[j]*maskx[2][1]+ptr0[j+1]*maskx[2][2]);

     convy[i][j]=(double)ptr1[j-1]*masky[1][0]+ptr1[j]*masky[1][1]+ptr1[j+1]*masky[1][2] + (ptr2[j-1]*masky[0][0]+ptr2[j]*masky[0][1]+ptr2[j+1]*masky[0] + ptr0[j-1]*masky[2][0]+ptr0[j]*masky[2][1]+ptr0[j+1]*masky[2][2]);

    double eq2=pow(convx[i][j],2)+pow(convy[i][j],2);
    M[i][j]=(double)sqrt(eq2);
}
}
```

Comment: Access violation usually means you're trying to access memory that you shouldn't be. A) can you tell us on which line this happens, B) are you sure your indices are in the correct ranges?

Comment: What value does SIGMA have? Access out of bounds will happen in `gaussian_mask()` if SIGMA is greater than 0.3333.

Comment: @user2151446 i was earlier using the value 1, following your suggestion i also tried it with 0.333 but it didn't help.

Comment: @Borgleader the error is taking place in the inner for loop in convolve function where i am providing values for convx and convy.
Also the error takes place after it tries to access row no. 490 in my 640x480 image

Comment: @user2558879 The the range of indices to maskx/y is 0 to 2*MaskWidth. With SIGMA=1, MaskRadius=3. Therefore the range is 0 to 6.  However the legal indices is 0,1,2. While the access violation may be happening for some other reason,  `gaussian_mask()` is seriously broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The access violation can happen when you are creating the mask, when you are converting the image, or when you are doing the convolution. You can start by commenting out all code and then uncommenting it from top, while observing which line/block gives you the error. Also use the debugger of the IDE to see the values of indexes, and check for those going out of range.

Comment: it is taking place when i am doing the convolution ; and when i am assigning values to convx and convy arrays to be specific.
the code runs fine for the first 480 rows and then it suddenly breaks.

Comment: If your image is 640*480, the number of rows is 480 and the number of columns 640. Have you exchanged these two by any chance?

Comment: Ehm, just wondering why my answer has been down-voted, when it is marked as the answer to this question :-(